# The relationship between angular and linear momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, momentum

Why is orbital angular momentum not 0 when spin and linear momentum are not collinear?

Why can it be 0 when spin and linear momentum are parallel?

Like in the example of a scalar field at rest decaying into an electron and a positron via interaction $\frac{1}{2}g\phi \bar{\Psi}\Psi $

If spin is along x axis and three-momenta is along z axis, decay rate will be 0 if two spins are opposite because orbital momentum is not 0 after decaying.

Comment: Can you give more context for your question or provide the example that you're thinking of? It will probably be easier to address your question if you do.

Comment: Copy that. I have added an example in the question.